# How to ignore a missing migration with "sequel -s"

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm trying to use Sequel to manage migrations for my database, and sometimes, due to feature-branching, there are moments when the database has migrations applied that don't exist in the filesystem.

By default, when I apply migrations with `sequel -m` on those situations I get this error:

```
Error: Sequel::Migrator::Error: Applied migration files not in file system
```

"[Migrations](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/migration_rdoc.html)" says there's an option for that:

> ### Ignoring missing migrations
>
> In some cases, you may want to allow a migration in the database that does not exist in the filesystem (deploying to an older version of code without running a down migration when deploy auto-migrates, for example). If required, you can pass :allow_missing_migration_files => true as an option. This will stop errors from being raised if there are migrations in the database that do not exist in the filesystem.

Nice!

How do I pass that `allow_missing_migration_files` option to `sequel -m`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'll have to use the `Sequel::Migrator API` for that. Something like

```
Sequel::Migrator.run(DB, '/path/to/migrations/dir', allow_missing_migration_files: true)
```

You can also wrap this behavior in a Rake task, so you don't have to start a console to run migrations.

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Run migrations ignoring the missing ones"
  task :migrate_without_missing, [:version] do |t, args|
    require "sequel"
    Sequel.extension :migration
    db = Sequel.connect(ENV.fetch("DATABASE_URL"))
    if args[:version]
      puts "Migrating to version #{args[:version]}"
      Sequel::Migrator.run(db, "db/migrations", target: args[:version].to_i, allow_missing_migration_files: true)
    else
      puts "Migrating to latest"
      Sequel::Migrator.run(db, "db/migrations", allow_missing_migration_files: true)
    end
  end
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate_without_missing`.

Comment: YEAH! Thanks mate.